# Подскажите дополнение чтобы можно организовать поиск по 3 полям

Tags: php, javascript, cms, modx

Пробовал SimpleSearch для организации поиска, по одному полю ищет, по 3 не выводит ничего

```
    <form class="form-inline " action="[[~[[+landing]]]]" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group form-s">
<select name="[[+searchIndex]]"> 
<option value="Москва">Москва</option>
</select>
            <input type="text" id="text_search"  class="form-control " name="[[+searchIndex]]" value="[[+searchValue]]" placeholder="Введите текст для поиска" />
<select name="[[+searchIndex]]"> 
<option value="15">15</option>
</select>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="[[+landing]]" />
            <input type="submit" id="seach_submit" class="form-control btn btn-default " value="[[%sisea.search? &namespace=`sisea` &topic=`default`]]" >

        </div>
    </form>
```

Или это дополнение не может делать поиск по 3 полям?

может есть какое другое дополнение?

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё один поисковый движок, называется AdvSearch, у него есть недокументированные возможность и вобще он романтичный, но он небыстро работает особенно с неоптимальными настройками. Но если сервер быстр, то можно даже сделать быстрый поиск с выдачей по мере ввода.